# How to implement Datatable in boostrap table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, datatable

I want create Jquery Datatable with Paging,Sorting,Searching in my ASP.NET web Api project as [this youtube clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Op29UMdIqKk)

in my bootstrap table as shown below. I don not recieve any Error but not showing me pagin field, serach field .. nothing showing me just my table. I understan it's not the same table form as that youtube clip but how should I do have the same functionality as him.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Countries</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script> // Tried even with jquery-1.12.4.js
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/DataTables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table table-responsive success" id="countriesTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                       Country Id
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Country name
                    </th>

                    <th class="col-md-2">
                       Action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="tbody"></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#countriesTable').DataTable({
                "bSort": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bProcessing": true
            });
loadCountries();
}

function loadCountries() {

            $('#compTable').DataTable({
                "bSort": true,
                "bFilter": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bProcessing": true
            });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Api/Countries",
                type: "GET",

                headers: {

                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('accessToken')

                },

                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(result, function (key, item) {


                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.CountryId + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.CountryName + '</td>';


                        html += '<td><Button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return getByID(' + item.CountryId + ')">Edit</button>  <Button                         class="btn btn-danger btn-md" onclick="return Delete(' + item.CountryId + ')">Delete</Button></td>';
                        html += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('.tbody').html(html);
                },
                error: function (jqXHR) {

                    if (jqXHR.status == "401") {
                        $('#errorModal').modal('show');
                    }
                    else {
                        $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#divError').show('fade');
                    }



                }
            });
        }


  </script>
```

Comment: Wilander.: Check my answer...hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize the table correctly and also add proper dependent library from the documentation page. To get you started

```
$('#countriesTable').DataTable({
            "bSort": true,
            "bFilter": true,
            "bPaginate": true,
            "bProcessing": true
        })
```

For the small arrow buttons in the column heads (which indicates sorting direction etc.) you need to add proper glyphicon libraries.

You can learn more options [here](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/features).

How to find the proper dependent library?

Check this [example](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html). In the example section there 3 parts HTML, CSS and javascript. They mentioned the libraries there. You need to add them in the correct order they are mentioned.

As per your requirement you need to feature that dattable provides with table generation. After ajax call is made a response is found. Now you get the data from it and map it to appropriate columns.

```
$('#my-table').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url:websiteurl,
      data:function(dtl){
      }
    },
    columns: [
     { data: 'col1'},
     { data: 'col2'}, 
    ]
   });
```

HTML:

```
        <table id ="my-table" class="table table-striped table-responsive sorting "  >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <td>col1</td>
                <td>col2</td> 


                </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

### Remember

For this you hvae to build the json output in the fom of array of objects.

```
             JSONArray ja= new JSONArray();
             JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
             jo.put("col1",col1val);
             jo.put("col2",col2val);

             ja.put(jo);
             return ja in the response.
```

#### You might think

Can I put a html button code in a json string ..yes you can. Try that.

Referrence:[Link](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't how to add glyphicon icons but I will search on youtue, but I don't understand when you say "add proper dependent library" .. how shall I know or how shall I do to add dependency library? I tried  your code without "adding proper dependent library" but offfcourse not working. Thank you again

Comment: @JonasWillander.: Check the answer..if it helps select my answer. it helps future users.

Comment: Now I have edited my code, please check. I did as I understand as you wrote but what now happening is it shows me all when I reload first time my page, but when I click anywhere on serach or change "show entire" or the small button , then disapears all my data. My table becomes empty, and if I refresh my page all countries name loads (almost 40 country) It is Asp.Net web api and It's working fine with my "Normal table" But I want implment DataTable to my table. Maybe you know what's wrong with my code..please Help..;)

Comment: @JonasWillander.: How do you populate your table?

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, Now I have edited with hole code... I mean HTMl and jquery ..page to load countries from my Api... please check my edited code again.

Comment: @JonasWillander.: You can populate the table this way.

Comment: Greate.. now it's working fine. Thank you very much!